# Use `OAT++` to develop Webserver can not bind the ipv4 address

Tags: networking, serversocket, oat++

On Tencent cloud Server to do. I used `0.0.0.0` to bind the listening port, and an error occurred when running. If I use the `ip` found in `localhost` or `ifconfig`, there will be no error. Because `ifconfig` contains the intranet address. I want it to be accessible from the public network.

The following is the log where the error occurred：

```
 E |2023-09-15 17:19:37 1694769577143334| [oatpp::network::tcp::server::ConnectionProvider::instantiateServer()]:Error. Couldn't bind. Cannot assign requested address
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  [oatpp::network::tcp::server::ConnectionProvider::instantiateServer()]: Error. Couldn't bind Cannot assign requested address
```

Related code:

```
void run() {

  /* Create Router for HTTP requests routing */
  auto router = oatpp::web::server::HttpRouter::createShared();
  
  /* Route GET - "/hello" requests to Handler */
  router -> route("GET", "/hello", std::make_shared<Handler>());
  router -> route("GET", "/huang", std::make_shared<Huang>());
  /* Create HTTP connection handler with router */
  auto connectionHandler = oatpp::web::server::HttpConnectionHandler::createShared(router);

  /* Create TCP connection provider */
  auto connectionProvider = oatpp::network::tcp::server::ConnectionProvider::createShared({"0.0.0.0", 8000, oatpp::network::Address::IP_4});

  /* Create server which takes provided TCP connections and passes them to HTTP connection handler */
  oatpp::network::Server server(connectionProvider, connectionHandler);

  /* Priny info about server port */
  OATPP_LOGI("MyApp", "Server running on port %s", connectionProvider->getProperty("port").getData());

  /* Run server */
  server.run();
}
```

output of ifconfig

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.12.8  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 10.0.15.255
        inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe9b:8c05  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:00:9b:8c:05  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 83825  bytes 64075575 (64.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 57376  bytes 24188720 (24.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (local loopback)
        RX packets 24642  bytes 6743792 (6.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 24642  bytes 6743792 (6.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

What should I do can listen public network?